# AngularJS trouble with UI-Router and linking id from one controller to another

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I originally had my app set up with ng-route and I'm now switching over to ui-route. I used to use "when('/json/galleries/:projectId')" to generate a gallery when a thumbnail was clicked. Now with "state" I can't seem how to pass my projectId to the gallery state to generate my gallery.

App Module

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  var bhamDesignsApp = angular.module('bhamDesignsApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ngTouch', 'ngSanitize', 'ngMessages', 'ngAria', 'ui.router', 'mm.foundation', 'appControllers']);

    bhamDesignsApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

        $stateProvider

        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
            controller: 'ProjectsController'
          })

        .state('gallery', {
          url: '/gallery/:projectId',
          templateUrl: 'partials/gallery.html',
          controller: 'GalleryController'
        });
      });
})();
```

App Controller

```
(function() {

'use strict';

var appControllers = angular.module('appControllers', []);

appControllers.controller('ProjectsController', ['$scope', '$http',
  function ($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('app/json/projects.json').success(function(data){
    $scope.projects = data;
  });

  $scope.orderProp = '-year';

}]);

appControllers.controller('GalleryController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$http',
  function($scope, $stateParams, $http) {
    $http.get('app/json/galleries/' + $stateParams.projectId + '.json').success(function(data) {
      $scope.gallery = data;
    });
}]);

})();
```

HTML

```
.row
  .small-12.medium-3.columns(ng-repeat="project in projects | orderBy:orderProp | filter:categoryFilter")
    .tmbnail-container    
      a(ui-sref="gallery")
        img.tmbnail(ng-src="{{project.thumbnail}}")
        .text 
          h5 {{project.title}}
          h6 {{project.year}}
  .small-12.medium-6.columns
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a(ui-sref="gallery")
```

You don't pass any ID to the state.

Change it to

```
a(ui-sref="gallery({projectId: project.id})"
```

(assuming project has an `id` field that holds its ID)

Documentation that explains how to use ui-sref: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref

Comment: Works like magic! I think i originally had gallery({projectId:}) but it wouldn't work because I was missing the second part. Thanks for the help, now to read the documentation and figurer out how this mysticism works.